# Virtual Machine or Host?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

Is there a way to find out if the (linux) system that I'm logging into is a host or a VM? Any symptoms that I can look at via the shell or any other utility (of a VM)?

Comment: By definition of a good enough VM there should be no way to find out....

Comment: And if you really depend on a way to find out, you may discover that VMs will evolve towards blurring your way to detect them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a number if scripts available, that try to detect the presence of virtualisation.
e.g. [virt-what](http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/virt-what/), but i guess there is no generic solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the Drivers which has been loaded incase of full Virtualization environemnt such as VMware. using lspci,lsmod, ... etc. or you can use dmesg to get this kind of information.

Comment: Thanks. dmesg | grep "Linux version" worked for me in one case. (kernel info) Didn't work for me in another case. I guess there's no sure way to it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the perl module Sys::Detect::Virtualization [here](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Sys-Detect-Virtualization/script/virtdetect)

```
use Sys::Detect::Virtualization;

my $detector = eval { Sys::Detect::Virtualization->new() };
if( $@ ) {
    print "Detector may not be supported for your platform.  Error was: $@\n";
}

my @found = $detector->detect();
if( @found ) {
    print "Possible virtualized system.  May be running under:\n";
    print "\t$_\n" for @found;
}
```

Comment: Please do explain more. See [answer]?